# Run-time error 2471 access vba

Tags: vba

Please, HELP
I have a login form where Combo box contains 3 fields (EmployeeID, Employee Name: [FirstName] & " " & [LastName], JobTitle - qry picked). In dropdown list is only one field shown (properties set 0', 1', 0' width). Also frmLogin contains a text box to enter a password and there are two hidden text boxes (Name and JobTitle for other functions to perform). When I choose the UserName, hidden boxes are populated; however, when I enter password, the popup window shows up with Run-time error ‘2471’ - The expression you entered as a query parameter produced the following error: ‘admin’.

Here is a code to log in.

```
Private Sub cmdLogin_Click()

If IsNull(Me.cboLoginName) Or Me.cboLoginName = "" Then
MsgBox "You must select an employee name.", vbOKOnly, "Required data"
Me.cboLoginName.SetFocus
Exit Sub
End If

If IsNull(Me.tbxPassword) Or Me.tbxPassword = "" Then
MsgBox "You must enter a password", vbOKOnly, "Required data"
Me.tbxPassword.SetFocus
Exit Sub
End If
'next line is highlighted as error
If Me.tbxPassword.Value = DLookup("Password", "tblEmployees", "[EmployeeID]=" & Me.cboLoginName.Value) Then
Me.Visible = False
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmEntry"
Else

MsgBox "Invalid employee name / password combination. Please try again.", vbOKOnly, "Invalid Entry!"
Me.tbxPassword.SetFocus

End If

End Sub
```

[Query for the combobox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyKR5.jpg)

Comment: Have you placed a breakpoint on the failing line and examined the content of 'Me.cboLoginName.Value' ... and I assume that is numeric, else you need quotes around the string.

Comment: Everything worked fine before I added JobTitle to qry for the combobox. There were only EmployeeID, Employee Name: [FirstName] & " " & [LastName]. But I needed to have JobTitle for other things. Probably code doesn't know which field to take.

Comment: Put the breakpoint in, view the content of Me.cboLoginName.Value. It may not be what you expect ... i.e. adding a column to the combobox may have shifted your column alignment... soundls like 'Admin' is a job title????

Comment: me.cboLoginName.Value = admin.  And "Admin" it is a username

Comment: So, does that translate into: Find the 'password' field in table 'tblEmployees' where the 'EmployeeID' = 'Admin'? Is 'EmployeeID' a numeric field? If not, I earlier suggested quotes; but now knowing it is alpha, you need quotes. But I think the issue is with using the wrong column (you did say Admin is a user name and not an 'EmpID')

Comment: EmployeeID is autonumber, "Admin" is a Last name and no first name, but other employees have First and Last. I tried to use quotes for Me.cboLoginName.Value as `If Me.tbxPassword.Value = DLookup("[Password]", "tblEmployees", "[EmployeeID]='" & Me.cboLoginName.Value & "'") Then`

Comment: Yes, I think it uses wrong column. And that's why I tried to change code to ..

Comment: Let's reset now: (1) EmpID is an AutoNumber, which means it is numeric - not alpha; (2) Your combobox column contains 'Admin', which is NOT numeric; (3) Either you are using: (a) the wrong combobox column, or (b) the wrong field to search the table with. I would use the breakpoint, then in the immediate window, check column 0, 1, 2, 3... until you find the EmpID, then use that column in your DLookup.

Comment: `If IsNull(Me.cboLoginName.Column(1)) Or Me.cboLoginName = "" Then
MsgBox "You must select an employee name.", vbOKOnly, "Required data"
Me.cboLoginName.Column(1).SetFocus
Exit Sub
End If
If IsNull(Me.tbxPassword) Or Me.tbxPassword = "" Then
MsgBox "You must enter a password", vbOKOnly, "Required data"
Me.tbxPassword.SetFocus
Exit Sub
End If

If Me.tbxPassword.Value = DLookup("Password", "tblEmployees", "[EmployeeID]=" & Me.cboLoginName.Value) Then

Me.Visible = False
'DoCmd.OpenForm "frmAllCrossings"
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmEntry"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I don't know the rowsource of your combobox or the number of columns your control specifies, paste the following code before your DLookup and see which column you should be using:

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To Me.cboLoginName.ColumnCount
    Debug.Print "Column " & i & " contains '" & Me.cboLoginName.Column(i) & "'"
Next i
```

Comment: THank you, I will try this, and let you know how it will work

Comment: When I added this code before the DLookup it showed me i=4 (but I have only 3 columns (0,1,2) in my query in the combobox).

Comment: When I am trying this `If Me.tbxPassword.Value = DLookup("[Password]", "tblEmployees", "[EmployeeID]= '" & Me.cboLoginName.Column(1) & "'") Then` I am receiving Run-time error 3464 (Data type mismatch in criteria expression).

Comment: I think we are having a problem understanding one another. You say there are only three columns in your query, yet above you say you added 'JobTitle', which would have been the 4th. You also say my code shows 'i=4', but you never mention the other data like "Column n contains '????' Please show the entire results ... you have a mismatch between your query, combobox and which column you are selecting. This code is wrong: "DLookup("Password", "tblEmployees", "[EmployeeID]=" & Me.cboLoginName.Value)" - unless cboLoginName contains the EmployeeID - or you specify the correct column.

Comment: Yes, I added "Job Title" and it is a 3rd column. And I mentioned that my query contains 3 columns in my question - in very beginning. Also, when I add your code to my existing one before DLookup, it doesn't give me exact result, just the same error with highlighted line - nothing new), and when I hover mouse `" & i &  "`it shows me i=4. Also `DLookup("Password", "tblEmployees", "[EmployeeID]=" & Me.cboLoginName.Value)` works perfectly without new added Job Title field to the query (where cboLoginName contains the EmployeeID and Employee Name: [FirstName] & " " & [LastName]  columns).

Comment: I am just trying to find a solution, not to make you confused. I am working with vba not for a long time, that's why asking people here for help.

Comment: You need to look in the 'Immediate Window' for the results of my 'Debug.Print' Since you see 'I=4', that means there have been THREE prior displays made to the Immediate Window. It is very important as to what value is shown for 0, 1, and 2. I'm guessing you added 'JobTitle' to the query BEFORE the EmployeeID and EmployeeName fields? If so, that is the issue: you need to change ".Column(1)" to ".Column(2)", but it would be really simple if you could confirm that by showing the results from the Immediate Window.

Comment: No, it is last one. I added a screenshot of my query to the question. Immediate window shows me `Column 0 contains '8'`
`Column 1 contains 'admin '`
`Column 2 contains 'test test'`  (8 - EmployeeID, admin - Employee Name: [FirstName] & " " & [LastName], test test - job title)

Comment: (1) What is the setting for 'Bound Column' for cboLoginName? It should be 1. (2) Is table field EmployeeID defined as a numeric field?

Comment: The settings for "Bound Column' for cboLoginName was 2 (I think I changed it accidentally because it was suppose to be 1). So, I changed it back to 1 and now it works! Thank you very much for your patience and help!